# Отправка Biginteger чисел через UDP

Tags: c#, udp, biginteger

Есть класс, который я сериализую в xml и передаю через `UDP`. На стороне приемника числа почему то пустые, т.е просто нули. Хотя текст сообщения сохраняется) Мне кажется какие то проблемы возникают при передаче больших чисел через `UDP`.

PS. Пишу программу для проверки цифровой подписи по Эль-Гамалю. Хочу отправить открытый ключ и подпись по UDP.

```
[Serializable]
public class PublicKeyAndSignature // Открытый ключ и подпись
{
    public string M { get; set; } // Message
    public BigInteger r { get; set; } // 
    public BigInteger s { get; set; } //
    public BigInteger p { get; set; }
    public BigInteger g { get; set; }
    public BigInteger y { get; set; }
}


XmlSerializer xml_ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PublicKeyAndSignature));
            MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();

            var key = Gamal.Encode("Привет");

            xml_ser.Serialize(str, key);
            buffer = str.ToArray();
            str.Close();

            try
            {
                s.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DoSend), s);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего отправку данных делать через бинарную сериализацию.

```
  var key = Gamal.Encode("Привет",p,g,x,k); // Текст для подписи
  MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
  MemoryStream stream = ElgamalLib.Gamal.SerializeToStream(key);
  buffer = stream.ToArray();
  str.Close();

try
        {
            s.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DoSend), s);
        }


 public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
            return stream;
        }

        public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return o;
        }
```